# How do I write a function in Rust that accepts any iterator whose Item fulfills a trait?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Here is a contrived example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
trait Double {
    fn get(&self) -> i32;
}

impl Double for i32 {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 { self * 2 }
}

fn foo<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a Double>>(is: I) {
    for i in is {
        println!("{}", i.get());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let is = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    foo(is.into_iter());
}
```

The error here says "expected integral variable, found `&Double`".

I'm having trouble googling for this as everywhere talks about iterators as traits. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound `Iterator<Item = &'a Double>>` says that you want an iterator which yields items of exactly the type `&Double` which denotes the trait object of the trait `Double`. But you want an iterator that yields any type which implements the trait `Double`. This sounds very similar and thus confusing, but this is all about dynamic vs static dispatch. You should read the Rust book chapter about [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) to understand what exactly is going on.

But a quick summary: there is a difference between writing

```
fn foo<T: MyTrait>(t: &T) {}
```

and

```
fn foo(t: &MyTrait) {}
```

You wrote code equivalent to the latter, but actually want the former.

---

So how do you express your intend in code? One possibility is to introduce another type parameter!

```
fn foo<'a, T, I>(is: I) 
    where T: Double,
          I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
{
    for i in is {
        println!("{}", i.get());
    }
}
```

But you can also just bound the associated type of the iterator (see [Francis Gagné's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058022/2408867)):

```
fn foo<I>(is: I) 
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: Double,
{ ... }
```

However, these two versions are slightly different as one accepts an iterator over references to types implementing `Double` while the other one iterates over types implementing `Double` directly. Just use what fits you the best or generalize those two things with traits like [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html).

Comment: ah nice, so this is static dispatch yeah? i don't want to introduce an overhead by doing this.

Comment: @SamKellett Yes, exactly, this is static dispatch (dynamic dispatch is only used if you see something like `&MyTrait`, `&mut MyTrait` or `Box<MyTrait>`)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use a `where` clause to specify a bound on the associated type `I::Item`.

```
fn foo<I>(is: I)
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: Double,
{
    for i in is {
        println!("{}", i.get());
    }
}
```

(I've also moved the `I: Iterator` bound to the `where` clause to keep all the bounds together.)

Comment: this is nice as it doesn't add the extra type parameter

Comment: Yep, this is better than my original solution. I added this solution to my answer as well, as you (Sam) already accepted mine. I hope you don't mind, Francis.

Comment: No problem. Our solutions are not quite identical, though: my version requests an iterator of doubles, while your version requests an iterator of *references* to doubles; you might want to mention this.

Comment: @FrancisGagné Oh thank you ♥ Wasn't paying attention to that. Mentioned it :)